# SQL Server encrypt mdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database SQL server ,so I have 2 files (mdf and log).
how to protect mdf file from attach

Comment: Well you don't have to because it would not attach to the server unless it has first been unattached!

Comment: What version & edition of SQL Server are you using?  Eg, 2012 Standard, etc.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017) can prevent people from using the files elsewhere unless they have the appropriate certificates.

But if they've gained access to the server to the point where they can access those files directly, you have to consider the possibility that it's completely compromised.